# Wordpress woocommerce shortcode button is not displaying on editor

Tags: woocommerce

I have network activated woocommerce and I have it activated on my current site. I don't know why I don't see the short code woocommerce button so i can create a feature items section under my main photo. LEt me know if someone can kindly find a solution.

Thanks so much in advanced!

Comment: Please close up this question, if my answer solved your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This button [has been removed](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/issues/5130), as of WooCommerce 2.2, due to incompatibility with WordPress 3.9+.

You can still use the normal shortcodes...there's just no longer a button for them.

If you need a button, there's an [official plugin for it](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-shortcodes/).